# Method in Service that uses excel isn't saving and doesn't appear to produce an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

I have a problem with some code in a service I have.  The method just creates a datatable of the report that needs to be created and then writes it to an existing excel file.  The problem is that it fails at the save of the file.  Somewhat more oddly, it doesn't appear to be catching errors, and I don't know why.  I've included the code below.  Of note:

1. excel.Visible=true; doesn't seem to make the excel sheet visible each time so I can't really watch what's going on in the excel itself. I assume it's not becoming visible because it's a service, but I don't really know.
2. I know that the datatable is producing output as I've had the log (Which is just a text file where I can write events and errors) writes both the cells value and it's location and it has never stopped in the Foreach loop or the for loop within it
3. I know that it's failing at the wb.Save(); because the Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 4"); successfully writes to the text file, but the Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 5"); does not.
4. The catch (Exception ex) also doesn't seem to be working, as it doesn't write anything about the exception but doesn't even write the Log.WriteLine("Catching Exception");, so I'm a bit lost.

Edit: Just to note, this is all using Interops in the excel portion.  It's just that the "using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" is declared at the top of the class to save time and typing as almost all the methods in this particular class are using excel.  The excel file is always opening in this process, I can see it in the task manager, and I have had other methods successfully write to excel files in this process.  Only this particular method has had issues.

```cs
public void WriteTIByEmp(CI.WriteReport Log)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Data.DataTable Emps = Pinpoint.TICardsByEmpStatsDaily.GetTICardsByEmployer();
            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 1");
            Application excel = new Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(TIEMPPath);
            Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
            ws.Range["A:G"].Clear();
            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 2");

            int RowNum = 0;
            int ColCount = Emps.Columns.Count;

            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 3");
            foreach (DataRow dr in Emps.Rows)
            {
                RowNum++;
                for (int i = 0; i < ColCount; i++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[RowNum, i + 1] = dr[i].ToString();
                    Log.WriteLine("Cell Val:" + dr[i].ToString() + ".  Cell Location: " + RowNum + "," + i);
                }
            }
            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 4");
            wb.Save();
            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 5");
            wb.Close();
            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 6");
            excel = null;
            Log.WriteLine("WriteTIByEmp 7");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLine("Catching Exception");

            var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
            var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
            var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

            string msg = "Component Causing Error:" + ex.Source + System.Environment.NewLine + "Error Message: " + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + "Line Number: " + line + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine;

            Log.WriteLine(msg, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the issue. The Excel file was open on someone else's computer which resulted in it not being able to save the file, but it couldn't display the excel popup because excel wouldn't become visible (I still don't know why but Probably something to do with it being a service).  So it just couldn't save but it wasn't a code error so it didn't show up in the log and couldn't continue so the code was just stuck.  I'll make a copy for the purposes of updating in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Meaby try to use Interops

i don't understand how Your code can start Excel application 
by this line :

```
Application excel = new Application();
```

try this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlexcel.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I'm importing the Microsoft Interop excel at the top of the class, I just didn't include all the class code.

"using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ;"

Answer (score 0):

I have been in similar situation.

**Note:** While using Interop Excel is a dependency as well as other processes accessing the file could cause issues. Therefore, I recommend using EPPlus Nuget Package as it works wonders.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Please refer to the below sample code.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ExcelFilesPath + "myExcelFile.xlsx");

using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    // Using Existing WorkSheet 1.
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    // Loading Data From DataTable Called dt.
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

    // If you want to enable auto filter
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFilter = true;

    // Some Formatting
    Color colFromHex = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00B388");
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells["D:K"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";
    ws.Cells["M:N"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

    pck.SaveAs(fi);

}
```

You can refer to the above code from my project. I am loading the DataTable data into my excel file by providing the Range or Starting Cell.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but my infant might be in college before i got approval from my company to download and install a third party library.